# Cannot get @Typeconverters to work in floor-flutter

Tags: database, flutter, typeconverter, floor

At the [Documentation](https://github.com/vitusortner/floor/tree/type-converters#type-converters) I can see that it should be supported, but I can not find the way to add the @TypeConverter into my app. I haven´t seen any example of it working or similar question at anywhere so I´m starting to think that either I haven´t added something or it is not available yet.

Here is my pubspec.yaml file in case someone ask for it:

```yml
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.2
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  intl: ^0.16.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.10
  json_annotation: ^3.1.0
  floor: ^0.14.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  floor_generator: ^0.14.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  json_serializable: ^3.5.0
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

add in your pubspec.yaml file this line

floor_annotation: ^1.0.0

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the code in your answer and provide more detail/clarity.

Comment: I dont know if that was the problem. Finally I decided to do some workarounds instead of using it cause is not in the main page of the doc and it´s quite hide and not many people are using it. Anyway, if you go to https://pub.dev/packages/floor_annotation they say "dont import this package"